# Java multi threading synchronisation not working for this for loop

Tags: for-loop, concurrency, synchronization

I am trying to use synchronization on a `for` loop and technically the for loop should be executed completely by one thread before allowing the next thread to execute.

I declared 3 threads, then executed it, but I'm getting the output of 3 threads simultaneously.

Please find my below code:

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
       DummyForSample1 t1 = new DummyForSample1();
       t1.setName("1st");
       t1.start();
       DummyForSample1 t2 = new DummyForSample1();
       t2.setName("2nd");
       t2.start();      
       DummyForSample1 t3 = new DummyForSample1();
       t3.setName("3rd");
       t3.start();      
    }
}
public class DummyForSample1 extends Thread {

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("its execting      " +     
            Thread.currentThread().getName());
        forloop();  
    }
    synchronized void forloop() {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "    " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
its execting      2nd
its execting      3rd
its execting      1st
3rd    0
3rd    1
3rd    2
3rd    3
3rd    4
3rd    5
3rd    6
3rd    7
2nd    0
3rd    8
1st    0
1st    1
1st    2
1st    3
1st    4
3rd    9
2nd    1
2nd    2
2nd    3
2nd    4
2nd    5
1st    5
2nd    6
1st    6
2nd    7
1st    7
2nd    8
1st    8
2nd    9
1st    9
```

Comment: `synchronized` locks on the monitor of the current object. You have different instances, therefore `synchronized` does nothing.

Comment: See the example in the link on how to use an external thread object. [producer_consumer](http://th-thielemann.de/development/java-tutorial/java_tutorial31_producer_consumer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `synchronised` keyword on a method. This means you are synchronising on the current object instance. As you have three different instances of 'DummyForSample1' nothing prevents your threads to enter the same method concurrently.

Make sure that all threads are using the same object for locking. In your example you can use a static member to achieve this, like this:

```
public class DummyForSample1 extends Thread {

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("its execting      " +
                Thread.currentThread().getName());
        forloop();
    }

    void forloop() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "    " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander , i understood the point you are trying to make. I used your code , but im not getting the o/p as expected. Can you help me?

Comment: Which output did you get?

Comment: the same one as shown in my question... im expecting an o/p as follows:        Thread one o/p from 1 to 10 followed by thread two followed by thread three out put.  and not a mix up as shown in my question.

Comment: As the threads are started concurrently you can not determine which one gets executed first. In order to have the order fixed (1, 2, 3) you would have to synchronise the creation as well. But then you have an async program and threading make no sense at all.

Comment: thanks for your inputs... understood your point completely... Seems i should exercise more to understand this more quickly.